# Есть ли ограниения на размер команды, отправляемой на ssh сервер?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, ssh, openssh

Например, хочу сделать `ssh user@ip echo some_long_text`.
Какой лимит ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK у `ssh` нет какого-либо ограничения на размер командной строки, но оно есть у самого сервера, узнать его можно с помощью `getconf ARG_MAX`. Это полный размер всего буфера, который передаётся в адресное пространство процесса после `execve(2)` т.е. включает имя команды, все аргументы с заключающими нулями, а также *все переменные среды и их значения*.

Минимальное значение этого параметра [согласно POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/limits.h.html) равно `4096`. Но по умолчанию на многих современных linux-системах он имеет размер порядка двух мегабайт (четверть от максимального размера стека, см. `ulimit -s`), но не может быть меньше `128k` (32 4k-страницы).[[1]](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/fs/exec.c#L194)

Как практический безопасный максимум для произвольной системы я бы ограничился половиной значения POSIX: `2048` байт, хотя если известно, что целевая система — linux, то вполне можно увеличить его до `64k` или `100k`.